# What can cause Program Counter to have an invalid address?

Tags: c, debugging, vxworks, powerpc

I am getting an exception "Invalid Program Counter Address" in Vxworks + PPC 603.

Application is linking to multiple 'C' libraries. Am not able to place, what could cause this problem?

Is there a possibility that incorrect compilation options could be causing this?

Any directions or pointers will be helpful.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I am having a structure whose members are function pointers. The structure itself is static and it's address is passed around and through the structure different functions are being invoked.

During one of the test rounds, I found that in the function pointer, the function address value is reduced by 1. If the function address is 0x009a3730, the PC is having 0x00913729.

Also, if I change the compiler options, the place of crash or the number of runs after which the crash happens changes.

Comment: Are you doing any function calls via function pointers?

Comment: Probably your stack is mangled and you're popping an invalid address into the PC on return from a function.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, Yes, I am doing most of the function calls via function pointers only.

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings related to your use of function pointers ?

Comment: Could it be that you go over some array bounds and overwrite those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@All, Thanks for your suggestions.

It turned out that the location containing the address was incorrectly getting pointed to a reference member of another structure and that reference member was getting decremented by one in each call to free that structure.

The memory for that structure should have been allocated by a call to one of our functions. But, instead it was left to refer to some garbade memory without any initalization or memory allocation and it ended up referring to this static memory where the global structure is stored. This led to the static structure getting corrupted and which inturn led to the crash.

A thorough line-by-line analysis of our logs helped in putting all pieces together.

Answer (score 2):

Any case where you're working with function pointers can easily lead to this, if the pointer value gets corrupted and later is called. Check signal handlers if any, and any other API:s that deal with callbacks.

Comment: I am working with a struct whose members are are function pointers. The structure itself is static and the address of the static structure is being passed around. But,I am not understanding how to resolve this based on your answer. Can you please elaborate? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Jay: Basically, you're going to need to debug your application to find out where the function pointer has been corrupted.  You can place watchpoints on the function pointer in your `static` struct, and observe where it gets modfied.

Answer (score 0):

"If the function address is 0x009a3730, the PC is having 0x00913729". The difference here is not 1 :) However PC will always point to the address of the next instruction it has to execute AFAIK.

Maybe you could run the core dump in a debugger and print out the :

1. Back trace
2. 'disassemble' code around the region of the crash
3. info registers -> register values at the time of the crash
4. info locals --> local variables of the function inside which it crashed